# How can I disable Night Mode in Android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-dark-theme

I tried to delete night `theme.xml`, and I tried to make color changes in night theme. I also tried

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

But none of these worked.

This is my `theme.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.app" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/light_blue</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change both theme files with

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your App theme

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

(Both above answers ! and it works in jetpack compose)

Change both theme files with

```
<style name="Theme.PathFinder" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And add this in both theme files

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration of your style, try changing the parent directly to `Light` as follows :

```
<style name="Theme.app" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Still Not Working

Comment: @Faizan It does not work on Xiaomi devices 
u should add this code to your them


<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>